# DocumentsContract.copyDocument

Tags: file, permissions, copy

I have a problem with `DocumentsContract.copyDocument`

Each time my program crashes: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Copy not supported"
The curious thing is the below-listed actions are working **fine**!!

`DocumentsContract.moveDocument`

`DocumentsContract.deleteDocument`

`DocumentsContract.renameDocument`

`DocumentsContract.createDocument`

Permission to SD card access **is apparently granted** (above actions would fail without permission)

How come document moving, deleting and renaming is supported but not copying?
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Is there a great conceptual difference between copyDocument and moveDocument. Why move does work and copy does not?

Any hint will be highly appreciated

```
package com.example.forum14_11_2020;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.UriPermission;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.storage.StorageManager;
import android.os.storage.StorageVolume;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Uri uri;
    DocumentFile pickedDir;
    Button Button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button1 = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        Button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener_Button1);

        takeCardUriPermission("storage/1619-0D07");

    }


    View.OnClickListener onClickListener_Button1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            uri = getUri();
            pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getBaseContext(), uri);

            DocumentFile file = pickedDir.findFile("attempt.txt");
            DocumentFile folder = pickedDir.findFile("folder");

            try {
                //DocumentsContract.moveDocument(getContentResolver(), file.getUri(), folder.getUri(), folder.getUri()); // does work!
                //DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(getContentResolver(), file.getUri()); // does work!
                //DocumentsContract.renameDocument(getContentResolver(), file.getUri(), file.getName() + "_rename"); // does work!
                DocumentsContract.copyDocument(getContentResolver(), file.getUri(), folder.getUri()); // does not work

            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.getMessage();
            }

        }
    };





    public void takeCardUriPermission(String sdCardRootPath) {

        int stop=1;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            File sdCard = new File(sdCardRootPath);
            StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
            StorageVolume storageVolume = storageManager.getStorageVolume(sdCard);
            Intent intent = storageVolume.createAccessIntent(null);
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 4010);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            }
        }
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 4010) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
        }
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        List<UriPermission> persistedUriPermissions = getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
        if (persistedUriPermissions.size() > 0) {
            UriPermission uriPermission = persistedUriPermissions.get(0);
            return uriPermission.getUri();
        }
        return null;
    }






}
```

Comment: Same problem for me. Any solution?

Comment: Hi, SayantanRC! Not yet, so far I don't have a solution

Comment: the only alternative I think is to open input and output streams and copy through them.

Comment: yes, I suppose there are other ways to solve the issue. But anyway I was trying to find out a response to the question WHY copy only does not work, what is the sense of all of it :), I even thought that there is a problem with my PC software or hardware.
DocumentsContract's actions are quite a nice and relatively easy way to manipulate files, and it is pity to spend time trying to invent other (less logical) ways.
I'm sure there are people who know a reply, but it seems that the skilled people don't have time to reply :)

Comment: True. There are solutions, just the right people don't see the questions / busy to answer.

Comment: @SayantanRC here similar recent discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660155/android-saf-cannot-copy-file-flag-supports-copy-not-set

Comment: Yeah that guy has also given up. Its a shame that developers have to use all kinds of convoluted means to do such simple file operations.